# How can I use a custom method in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, repository, entitymanager

In my Data Repository I created a function:

```
  public function myData(){
    $data = $this->createQueryBuilder('data')
    ->leftJoin('data.fields', 'f')
    ->andWhere('f.name = :field')
    ->setParameter('field', 'company');
    $result = $data->getQuery()->execute();
  
    return $result;
}
```

In my Controller I want to use this function:

```
class PagesController extends AbstractController
{

 public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}


/**
 * @Route("/page", name="page", methods={"POST", "GET"})
 */
public function page(Request $request)
{

$data = $this->em->getRepository('App\\Entity\\Data')->myData();
```

But I get the error message:

> Undefined method 'myData'. The method name must start with either
> findBy, findOneBy or countBy!

Comment: Check your orm mapping.  Data is not correctly linked to DataRepository so getRepository just returns a generic repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject your repository in your controller:

```php
class PagesController extends AbstractController
{

 public function __construct(private DataRepository $dataRepository) {}


/**
 * @Route("/page", name="page", methods={"POST", "GET"})
 */
public function page(Request $request)
{

$data = $this->dataRepository->myData();
```

Comment: And can you explain how this would work when getRepo does not?  Hint: it does not.

Comment: Can you show your repository?

Answer (score 1):

In your myData function your using variable called $data but then in $result your using $qb...
You should change $data by $qb

Comment: Thank you!, this was just a type error here in the question